# Diferencias en la forma de obtener el context en Android

Tags: android, android-context

¿Cuáles son las diferencias esenciales entre los métodos `getContext()`, `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, y `this` para obtener el contexto en `Android`?

Se que puede ser una pregunta muy trivial o muy amplia, pero creo que a muchos de nosotros estos conceptos no nos quedan del todo claro y creo que sería de gran ayuda para la comunidad. Además si es posible pueden poner algún ejemplo básico de uso de cada caso para mejorar su comprensión.

P.D: con `this` me refiero a dentro de una `Activity`.

Comment: "pregunta muy trivial o muy amplia", no creo , al contrario creo que es una excelente pregunta para ayudar a diferenciar la obtención del contexto y que tipo de contexto se obtiene mediante estos métodos.

Comment: coincido con @Elenasys, nada trivial, muchos yo me incluyo, a veces no tienes claro porque tantos métodos para obtener el contexto en si.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Cuáles son las diferencias esenciales entre los métodos **getContext()**,
>   **getApplicationContext()**, **getBaseContext()**, y **this** para obtener el
>   contexto en Android?

**[getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext())**
Devuelve el contexto en el que se ejecuta la vista, usualmente la Activity, a través de este contexto se puede acceder al tema actual, recursos, etc.

**[getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext())**
Devuelve el contexto del objeto Application global único del proceso actual. Al usar este contexto se asegura tener un contexto atado a el ciclo de vida de la aplicación. Se podría decir que es el contexto más "light".

**[getBaseContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext())**:
El contexto base establecido por el constructor o setBaseContext.
Para hablar sobre este contexto es necesario hablar de [ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) que es una clase por medio de la cual se puede acceder a un contexto dentro de otro. El contexto del que se hace referencia [ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) es obtenido por medio de [getBaseContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext()). La obtención del contexto mediante este método es relacionado al de la Activity.

**This**: 
 Esta referencia se puede usar en una Activity ya que Activity hereda de  `Context` y es la referencia al contexto de la Activity :

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

---

> ¿porqué hay veces que no se puede acceder a ningún contexto?

Porque tu clase no extiende de `Activity`, `AppCompactActivity` o incluso de `Service` (donde se usa `this` para obtener el contexto), si tu clase no extiende de las mencionadas debes enviar a tu clase el contexto usando un constructor.

Ejemplo:

```
public class DownloadPdf extends Thread {

    private Context context;
    private DownloadPdfFileListener listener;
    private String pdfPath;

    /*Constructor recibe el contexto para ser usado en la clase*/  
    public DownloadPdf (Context context, String urlPdf, DownloadPdfFileListener listener){
        this.context = context;
        this.pdfPath = urlPdf;
        this.listener = listener;       
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys por tu respuesta, creo que nos servirá de ayuda a muchos!

Answer (score 2):

El `getApplicationContext()` se utiliza para obtener el Context asociado a la aplicación, por lo cual siempre será el mismo a lo largo del ciclo de vida de la app.
Por otra parte el `getBaseContext()` está asociado a la actividad padre, y no será necesariamente el mismo ya que está atado al ciclo de vida de ésta, por lo cual puede ser destruido.

En resumen, tú solo puedes tener 2 tipos de Context, el que se basa en la aplicación y el que se basa del activity, por lo cual dependiendo del requerimiento debes usar uno u otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @MZapatae

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces `this` dentro de una Activity en realidad lo que estas haciendo es coger el objeto `Activity` de tu actividad y de este Android ya coge el contexto. Una forma de comprobarlo es la siguiente:

Vamos a intentar llamar al método `getLayoutInflater()` dentro de tu actividad:

```
Context context= this;
Activity activity= this;

context.getLayoutInflater();
activity.getLayoutInflater();
this.getLayoutInflater(); 
getLayoutInflater(); //(EstoS dos ultimos casos son iguales)
```

Verás que con `context.getLayoutInflater();` te da error porque este método necesita llamarse con un objeto `Activity` y no con un `Context`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @borjis !