# anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context redquiereandroid.context context

Tags: onclicklistener, required

Importé una libreria para tener un toast personalizado. Pero al querer compilar la app me aparece un error.
EL termino resaltado es el de "this": error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Context

```
 button_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        //trataremos de implementar ek toasty
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int respuesta = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < ids_respuestas.length; i++) {
                if (ids_respuestas[i] == id) {
                    respuesta = i;
                }
            }
            if (respuesta == respuesta_correcta) {
                Toasty.success(this, "correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mp_baia_baia.start();
                score++;
                tv_score.setText("Score: " + score);
                Basededatos();

            } else{
                Toasty.error(this, "incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mp_ohperdon.start();
                huesitos--;
                Basededatos();

                switch (huesitos){
                    case 3:
                        iv_huesitos.setImageResource(R.drawable.craneo3);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        iv_huesitos.setImageResource(R.drawable.craneo2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        iv_huesitos.setImageResource(R.drawable.craneo1);
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();

                        break;
                }

            }

            if (pregunta_actual < todas_preguntas.length-1){
                pregunta_actual++;
                mostrarpregunta();
            }


        }
    });
```

En la linea

```
if (respuesta == respuesta_correcta) {
Toasty.success(this, "correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

me aparece este error sobre el termino :"this" :

> error: incompatible types:  cannot be
>   converted to Context.

Supuestamente la librería se habría importado sin problemas.
como debo cambiar el codigo?

Comment: En este caso puedes usar view.getContext(), revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37590/diferencias-en-la-forma-de-obtener-el-context-en-android saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya probaste usar getApplicationContext() en lugar del this?

Comment: Hola jose sanchez, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace `getApplicationContext()`? ¿Por qué usarlo en lugar de `this` solucionará el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de un listener no debes usar `this`, ya que estas haciendo referencia al mètodo del listener, en este caso debes usar:

> `getApplicationContext()` si te encuentras en una Activity.
>
> `getActivity()` si te encuentras en un Fragment.

Ejemplo:

```
button_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          //*Incorrecto! Toasty.success(this, "correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          //Correcto
          Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "mi mensaje", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         ...
         ...

         }
    }
```

incluso en este caso puedes usar el contexto de la vista usando `view.getContext()`:

```
 button_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          //*Incorrecto! Toasty.success(this, "correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          //Correcto
          Toasty.success(view.getContext(), "mi mensaje", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         ...
         ...

         }
    }
```

Revisa esta pregunta relacionada:

[Diferencias en la forma de obtener el context en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37590/diferencias-en-la-forma-de-obtener-el-context-en-android)